# add titles from a list to word file, vba code

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have three-page word document which contains heading level 1,2,3 titles and their page numbers, no other content. I'm looking for a way to copy each heading level into their respective page. is there any way to do this by vba code, macro please.

- heading level 1.....1 - To be copied to 1st page
- heading level  2.....15 - create blank pages and to be copied to page 15
- heading level 1.....17 - to be continued as above till end of the list
- heading level 2.....19

Comment: Do you mean `heading level 2` is the text on page 15? Are there always five dot before page number?

Comment: no dots. heading level 1 is just an example. format is some title formatted with word style heading level and the related page number with a space or tab or any other separator as long as this could be done automatically.

Comment: See Word Does Not Know What a Page Is by Word MVP Daiya Mitchell https://wordmvp.com/Mac/PagesInWord.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Five dots` are delimiter between `heading level text` and `page number`. Update as needed.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim Doc As Document, aLine, aTxt, j As Integer
    Dim i As Long, lPgNum As Long, sHeading As String
    Const DELI = "....."
    Set Doc = ActiveDocument
    aLine = Split(Doc.Content.Text, Chr(13))
    Doc.Content.Text = ""
    For i = 0 To UBound(aLine)
        ' Non-blank line and include DELI
        If Len(aLine(i)) > 0 And InStr(aLine(i), DELI) > 0 Then
            aTxt = Split(aLine(i), DELI)
            ' Move selection to the end
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory
            ' Total page number
            lPgNum = Doc.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
            If lPgNum < CInt(aTxt(1)) Then
                For j = 1 To CInt(aTxt(1)) - lPgNum
                    ' Insert page break
                    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
                Next
            End If
            ' Insert text and set style
            Selection.TypeText aTxt(0)
            Selection.Expand wdLine
            sHeading = Split(aTxt(0))(2)
            If VBA.IsNumeric(sHeading) Then _
                Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading " & sHeading)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Microsoft reference document:

> [Selection.InsertBreak method (Word)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.insertbreak?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: This is exactly what i need. Thank you. you made my day!